# HTML <tr> tag and position:relative

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am dealing with html writen long time ago and there is a problem with FireFox.
Some tr elements have position property set to relative , which surprisingly makes the border of those tr's invisble. When I remove the style, it all works fine... so the question is:
"**How does position:relative affect tr element?**" I can't get it.. for me it seems redundant.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

```
<table id="table1"  width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#cccccc"><tbody>
<tr class="header" style="position:relative;top:2 px;">
    <th>sdf</th>
    <th>sdf</th>
    <th>sdf</th>
</tr>

.header {
    position:relative;
}


table#table1 {
    border-collapse: collapse;    
}

#table1 th {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 8pt;
    padding: 3px;
    border-left: 1px solid #666666;
    border-right: 1px solid #666666;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666666;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #6685C2;
}

#table1 td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 8pt;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce it: http://jsfiddle.net/ABd9J/. On Firefox 5/Windows 7, the border is there with and without `position: relative`. Are you sure you've giving us correct code?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the code above. Now it can be reproduced , removing style and class from tr.

Comment: Per your instructions, this reproduces it: http://jsfiddle.net/ABd9J/3/

Comment: what I've also figured out is when I remove the  background-color for th element, the border becomes vivble... any ideas on that?

Comment: `table { border-collapse: separate }` works fine for me

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I'm also not entirely sure without seeing code, but:

From the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position

> The effect of 'position:relative' on table-row-group,
>   table-header-group, table-footer-group, **table-row,** table-column-group,
>   table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined.

`tr` is a `table-row`.

Comment: Maybe someone does not agree with this spec :(

Answer (score 5):

The interaction is probably that position:relative is disabling the border-collapse property. Of course, without seeing any code, it's pretty difficult to tell.

Update: If you look at your code you will see that the tr in question never has a border of its own. Setting `position: relative` affects display on the `th` elements. I suggest that you put this down to undefined behaviour.

If you need to position the row relatively, then I suggest that you also change it's display property to one appropriate for relative positioning.

Comment: I've posted the code. Note that when I remove the position:relative, border becomes visible.

Answer (score 2):

Use transform instead of position:

```
.header {
    transform: translateY(2px);
}
```