# Leaflet, how to put overlays above basemaps in control?

Tags: leaflet

In Leaflet control are overlays under basemaps. How to put them up? 
Just to swap position of overlayers/basemaps.

Comment: The order of those DOM elements is determined in code, with a separator between them. You could use jQuery to swap them as suggested in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38515050/3574481

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit, now with flex:

```
.leaflet-control-layers-expanded .leaflet-control-layers-list {
display:flex; flex-direction:column;}
.leaflet-control-layers-base { order:3 }
.leaflet-control-layers-separator {order:2}
```

Older:

```
.leaflet-control-layers-list {display:table; }
.leaflet-control-layers-base {display:table-footer-group; }
.leaflet-control-layers-overlays {display:table-header-group;}
.leaflet-control-layers-separator {display:none}
```

from: 
[CSS table rows reorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35257634/css-table-rows-reorder)