# How to fix gradient transition on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a hover transition from background to background gradient. But I want it to change the table row but instead it changes the whole background of the table.

Here's [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5jyveoqw/4/) to show what happens when you hover on the table row

I've tried using display block which changes the table row background with a transition but then it messes up my whole table row.

The background of the table changes but is has to change the table row only.

```css
.container #table {
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-spacing: 0px 15px;
}
.container #table tr {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #273240;
  z-index: 1;
}
.container #table tr::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #0089e0, #c0c1c1);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
  opacity: 0;
}
.container #table tr:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
.container #table tr th {
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #273240;
}
.container #table tr th:nth-child(n+5) {
  width: 75px;
}
.container #table tr td {
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: italic;
}
.container #table tr td:first-child {
  width: 25px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
.container #table tr td div {
  max-height: 70px;
  padding: 25px 0px;
  transition: max-height 0.5s, padding 0.5s;
}
.container #table tr td i {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>POS</th>
    <th>TEAM</th>
    <th>DRIVER</th>
    <th>MUG</th>
    <th>SPA</th>
    <th>BRN</th>
    <th>POR</th>
    <th>BAR</th>
    <th>TOT</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>1ST</td>
      <td>PROSPORT PERFORMANCE (85)</td>
      <td>ROBERT RENAUER</td>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>85</td>  
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: That's because you can't set a `tr`'s `position` to `relative`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6746339/863110. Why do you need the `::before` anyway?

Comment: To fake the transition with opacity since a background transition doens't work with gradients. Should I make a table with divs instead ?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7919377/863110) could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the background and the pseudo element on `th`/`td` instead and use `background-attachment:fixed` to simulate a continuous background:

```css
.container #table {
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-spacing: 0px 15px;
}
.container #table tr >* {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #273240;
  z-index: 1;
}
.container #table tr > *::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #0089e0, #c0c1c1) fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
  opacity: 0;
}
.container #table tr:hover > *::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
.container #table tr th {
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #273240;
}
.container #table tr th:nth-child(n+5) {
  width: 75px;
}
.container #table tr td {
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: italic;
}
.container #table tr td:first-child {
  width: 25px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>POS</th>
    <th>TEAM</th>
    <th>DRIVER</th>
    <th>MUG</th>
    <th>SPA</th>
    <th>BRN</th>
    <th>POR</th>
    <th>BAR</th>
    <th>TOT</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>1ST</td>
      <td>PROSPORT PERFORMANCE (85)</td>
      <td>ROBERT RENAUER</td>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>85</td>  
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```